# Is this a good way to export all entities of a type to a csv file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have millions of entities of a particular type that i would like to export to a csv file.  The following code writes entities in batches of 1000 to a blob while keeping the blob open and deferring the next batch to the task queue. When there are no more entities to be fetched the blob is finalized.  This seems to work for most of my local testing but I wanted to know:

If i am missing out on any gotchas or corner cases before running it on my production data and incurring $s for datastore reads.

If the deadline is exceeded or the memory runs out while the batch is being written to the blob, this code is defaulting to the start of the current batch for running the task again which may cause a lot of duplication.  Any suggestions to fix that?

```
def entities_to_csv(entity_type,blob_file_name='',cursor='',batch_size=1000):
  more = True
  next_curs = None
  q = entity_type.query()
  results,next_curs,more = q.fetch_page(batch_size,start_cursor=Cursor.from_websafe_string(cursor))
  if results:
    try:
      if not blob_file_name:
        blob_file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/csv',_blob_uploaded_filename='%s.csv' % entity_type.__name__)

      rows = [e.to_dict() for e in results]
      with files.open(blob_file_name, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,restval='',extrasaction='ignore',fieldnames=results[0].keys())
        writer.writerows(rows)

      if more:
        deferred.defer(entity_type,blob_file_name,next_curs.to_websafe_string())
      else:
        files.finalize(blob_file_name)
    except DeadlineExceededError:
      deferred.defer(entity_type,blob_file_name,cursor)
```

Later in the code, something like:

```
deferred.defer(entities_to_csv,Song)
```

Comment: the with will do the close() for you on exit scope, you don't need to call close() explicitly.

Comment: You are right, removed f.close()

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current solution is that your memory will increase with every write to preform to the blobstore. the blobstore is immutable and write all the data at once from the memory.

You need to run the job on a backend that can hold all the records in memory, you need to define a backend in your application and call defer with `_target='<backend name>'`.

Comment: Shay do you mean that files.open will first fit the whole current blob in memory and then write it back in its entirety when more rows are appended to it?  That sounds very suboptimal.  I am assuming that as long as the blob is open and not finalized, i can keep appending to it.

Comment: @Yasser you can but it will append to memory and hence blowing up your forntend instance.

Comment: but the taskqueue tasks dont have to run on the same instance do they? with a million records, even a backend will run into memory issues.

Comment: @Yasser no, I have not idea what will happend if the task will "jump" instances, it will probably won't work. blobs are not meant to be kept open outside the scope of the code. I'm guessing all this based on work I've done with blobstore and Cloud Storage. lets see if the AppEngine guys have something to add here.

Comment: Hmm. interesting.  Then it doesnt make much sense to have close and finalize as separate functions, dont you think.

Comment: @Yasser Valid thinking, maybe you can pass the blob file around, but I'm pretty sure that its data is saved in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Google I/O video, pretty much describes what you want to do using MapReduce, starting at around the 23:15 mark in the video.  The code you want is at 27:19

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/307/

Comment: mapreduce wont work for me because it has no way to filter entities so far.  In most normal scenarios, i would want to filter entities.

Comment: you don't need to filter entities to use mapreduce.  you can just map all entities of your kind.

Comment: what i meant was that in my implementation above i am not filtering entities yet but in real scenarios i would want to do that.  Mapreduce wont let me export only a subset of my entities of a kind.

Comment: Also notice that the demo process only ~900KB of data, i think it will break if the data will get very large and it won't chunk the data in the Cloud Storage.

Comment: I'm using mapreduce for a few things, but not writing CSV to file.  The default mapper takes all entities of a kind, but it's easy to write a mapper that takes a filtered subset.  I'm not sure exactly how the filewriter serializes the writing to file, but I think you're limited to 5TB files in Cloud Storage.  Overall for me,  mapreduce has been much easier, and WAY faster than batching requests of 1000 entities and handling the failure cases.

Comment: if you can point me to a custom mapper that can filter entities, that would be great